# How can I avoid iterating over a nil array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want avoid iterating over a nil array.

My bad solution:

```
if nil!=myArr
    myArr.each { |item|
      p item;
    }
 end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In ruby, only `nil` and `false` are considered as false.

```
if myArr
    myArr.each { |item|
      p item
    }
end
```

Comment: You can also collapse this to `myArr and myArr.each ...`

Answer (score 29):

For a simple one-liner, you might also use `unless myArr.nil?`

```
myArr.each { |item| p item } unless myArr.nil?
```

#### Updating for Ruby >= 2.3.0:

If you are comfortable with a `nil` return rather than avoiding execution entirely, you can use the [Safe navigation operator `&.`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812647/what-does-ampersand-dot-mean-in-ruby).  Note though that this differs slightly. Whereas the `unless` version will skip execution entirely, the `&.` will execute but return `nil`.

```
myArr&.each { |item| p item }
# returns nil
```

Comment: Using `nil?` is almost always extraneous unless you are specifically testing a value that could be the value `false`, not just false from a boolean perspective.

Comment: Use of & operator for ruby 2.3 is fantastic (myArr&.each { |item| p item })

Comment: Thanks for introducing & operator. It's fantastic!

Answer (score 13):

You can wrap the array value in `Array()`.

```
Array(myArr).each { |item| p item }
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#class-Array-label-Creating+Arrays), does this:

> An array can also be created by using the Array() method, provided by Kernel, which tries to call to_ary, then to_a on its argument.

Basically, this will convert a `nil` value to `[]`. Which would neither iterate, or throw an error. Fair warning, it will do the same to any value. `Array("string")` will create `["string"]`.

Comment: @muistooshort GetSet's answer works only for Rails.  This answer works for plain Ruby as well.

Answer (score 3):

Simply checking for nil isn't always sufficient.  Sometimes a variable you expect to be an array can be initialized as a non-array object when there is only one.  It's not common, but proprietary services I've seen might give you a result of `nil`, `"Name1"`, or `["Name1", "Name2", ...]`.  To reliably handle this range of input, I prefer to access my arrays like this:

```
Array.wrap(myArr).each { |item|
  p item
}
```

[`Array.wrap`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-c-wrap) will convert `nil` to `[]`, `Object` to `[Object]`, and leave existing arrays alone.  Also handy for not silently butchering your hashes if one gets passed in instead of an array.  (Calling `Array(myArr)` will convert `myArr` into an array, which destroys hashes rather than wrapping them in arrays.

Comment: Plain ruby Array will also convert nil to [], Object to [Object], and leave existing arrays alone. You are right about Hashes.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, using [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/)

```
myArr.andand.each { | item| p item }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myArr ||= []
```

and then iterate.
This will assign empty array to myArr only if it's nil.

Comment: No, it won't. It will also assign if it is `false`.