# What does &. (ampersand dot) mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I came across this line of ruby code. What does `&.` mean in this?

```
@object&.method
```

Answer (score 362, accepted):

It is called the Safe Navigation Operator. Introduced in Ruby 2.3.0, it lets you call methods on objects without worrying that the object may be `nil`(Avoiding an `undefined method for nil:NilClass` error), similar to the [`try` method in Rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-try).

So you can write

```
@person&.spouse&.name
```

instead of

```
@person.spouse.name if @person && @person.spouse
```

From the [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+Navigation+Operator):

> `my_object.my_method`
>
> This sends the `my_method` message to `my_object`. Any
> object can be a receiver but depending on the method's visibility
> sending a message may raise a `NoMethodError`.
>
> You may use `&.` to designate a receiver, then `my_method` is not invoked
> and the result is `nil` when the receiver is `nil`. In that case, the
> arguments of `my_method` are not evaluated.

Comment: actually, it works like the `try!` method, not `try`

Comment: Wow.  I don't know how I missed this but rubocop just autocorrected my code to use in this tens of times.  Didn't even know it existed. Very cool.

Answer (score 97):

*Note: Even though @Santosh gave a clear and full answer, I would like add some more background and add an **important note** regarding its use with non instance variables.*

---

It is called "[Safe Navigation Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator)" (*aka "Optional chaining operator", "Null-conditional operator", etc.*). Matz seems to call it "lonely operator". It was [introduced in Ruby 2.3](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537). It sends a method to an object only if it is not `nil`.

#### Example:

```
# Call method `.profile` on `user` only if `user` is not `nil`
@user&.profile

# Equivalent to
unless @user.nil?
  @user.profile
end
```

#### "Edge case" with local variables:

Please note, above code uses instance variables. If you want to use safe navigation operator with local variables, you will have to check that your local variables are defined first.

```
# `user` local variable is not defined previous
user&.profile

# This code would throw the following error:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for main:Object
```

To fix this issue, check if your local variable is defined first or set it to nil:

```
# Option 1: Check the variable is defined
if defined?(user)
  user&.profile
end

# Option 2: Define your local variable. Example, set it to nil
user = nil
user&.profile     # Works and does not throw any errors
```

#### Method background

Rails has `try` method that basically does the same. It uses `send` method internally to call a method. [Matz suggested](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-on-heroku-with-matz) that it is slow and this should be a built-in language feature.

Many other programming languages have similar features: Objective C, Swift, Scala, CoffeeScript, etc. However, a common syntax is `?.` (question dot). But, this syntax could not be adopted by Ruby. Because `?` was allowed in method names and thus, `?.` symbol sequence is already a valid Ruby code. For example:

```
2.even?.class  # => TrueClass
```

That's why Ruby community had to come up with different syntax. It was an active discussion and different options were considered (`.?`, `?`, `&&`, etc.). Here is a list of some considerations:

```
u.?profile.?thumbnails
u\profile\thumbnails
u!profile!thumbnails
u ? .profile ? .thumbnails
u && .profile && .thumbnails

# And finally
u&.profile&.thumbnails
```

While choosing the syntax, developers looked at different edge cases and the discussion is quite useful to go through. If you want to go through  all variants and nuance of the operator, please see [this feature introduction discussion](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537) on official Ruby issue tracker.

Comment: `Many other programming languages have similar feature` that includes Python? [I don't think so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4978745/5958455).

Comment: @iBug did anyone mention Python? I don't think so.

Comment: Check my latest edit - I've removed it already.

Answer (score 11):

Be wary! Though the safe navigation operator is convenient it can also be easy to trick yourself into changing your logic with it. I recommend avoiding the use of it in flow control. Example:

```
str = nil

puts "Hello" if str.nil? || str.empty?
# The above line is different than the below line
puts "Hello" if str&.empty?
```

In the first example, `str.nil?` returns `true` and `str.empty?` is never called, causing the `puts` statement to be executed. In the second example however, `str&.empty?` returns `nil` which is falsey, and the `puts` statement is never executed.

Comment: `str&.empty?` is equivalent to `str && str.empty?`, of course `||` and `&&` are completely different operators! (BTW `str.nil? || str.empty?` is what ActiveSupport's `Object#blank?` does)

Answer (score 8):

`safe navigation operator (&.):` tells Ruby to only call the next method if the receiver isn’t nil. Otherwise, the expression returns nil.

---

**Practical In Action**

Let’s construct a `Roster` object for a `Sports team`. The `Roster` will contain `multiple Player` objects.

```
class Roster
  attr_accessor :players
end

class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :position
  
  def initialize(name, position)
    @name = name
    @position = position
  end

end
```

With these two objects, we can create a roster for a 2-on-2 women’s basketball tournament:

```
moore = Player.new("Maya Moore", "Forward")
taurasi = Player.new("Diana Taurasi", "Guard")
tourney_roster1 = Roster.new
tourney_roster1.players = [moore, taurasi]
```

If we want to know the forward for our `2-on-2` team, we might find the name this way:

```
if tourney_roster1.players.first.position == "Forward"
  puts "Forward: #{tourney_roster1.players.first.name}"
end
```

> But what if our opposing roster isn’t set correctly?

```
tourney_roster2 = Roster.new
if tourney_roster2.players.first.position == "Forward"
  puts "Forward: #{tourney_roster1.players.first.name}"
end
```

`tourney_roster2` hasn’t yet been set with any players. The preceding code will raise a `NoMethodError because tourney_roster2.players returns nil`. We can add conditional statements to avoid this, but it makes our if statement verbose and unclear:

```
if tourney_roster2.players &&
   tourney_roster2.players.first &&
   tourney_roster2.players.first.position == "Forward"
```

Instead, we can use the safe navigation operator to avoid the NoMethodError:

```
if tourney_roster2.players&.first&.position == "Forward"
  puts "Forward: #{tourney_roster1.players.first.name}"
end
```

Thus,

```
 >> tourney_roster2.players&.first == nil
  #=> true
 >> tourney_roster2.players&.first&.position == nil
  #=> true
```

**Some legitimate use cases:** The safe navigation operator comes in handy when working with multiple objects, as shown here, and when chaining methods together.

Answer (score 4):

it used for nil check, such as in kotlin and swift
For example;
with Object -> Swift and Kotlin

```
model = car?.model
```

this model can be nil(Swift) or null(Kotlin) if we have not defined the model value in car class.
we use that ampersand instead of question mark in ruby

```
model = car&.model
```

if use car.model without ampersand and if model is nil the system cannot continue running.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [short-read](https://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) (3 mins) I found on this - it is pretty good.

To add to the above, it acts like the `try!` method in [Rails](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-try-21), not the `try` method.

Because it will raise a `NoMethodError` exception if the receiver is not nil and does **not** implement the tried method.

Example taken from the above article:

```
account = Account.new(owner: Object.new)

account&.owner&.address
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `address' for #<Object:0x00559996b5bde8>`

account.try(:owner).try(:address)
# => nil

account.try!(:owner).try!(:address)
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `address' for #<Object:0x00559996b5bde8>`
```

Answer (score 0):

For all of those who came here from Typescript, it's the same as the `?` operator

Answer (score -1):

> what does mean `object&.an_attribute` in ruby on rails?

> I am new in Ruby on rails and I saw this kind of code but I don't understand it:

In Ruby, like in most mainstream programming languages, user code *cannot* modify the fundamental workings of the programming languages, nor can it change the programming language's syntax.

Since Ruby on Rails is just Ruby code, it should be immediately obvious that this cannot possibly have anything to do with Ruby on Rails.

Therefore, we need to look at Ruby for an explanation, not Ruby on Rails.

The *safe navigation operator* or *safe navigator* is specified in [`language/safe_navigator_spec.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/safe_navigator_spec.rb) of the [`ruby/spec`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/#readme), in particular [here](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/language/safe_navigator_spec.rb#L8-L23):

> ```ruby
> context "when context is nil" do
>   it "always returns nil" do
>     eval("nil&.unknown").should == nil
>     eval("[][10]&.unknown").should == nil
>   end
>
>   it "can be chained" do
>     eval("nil&.one&.two&.three").should == nil
>   end
>
>   it "doesn't evaluate arguments" do
>     obj = Object.new
>     obj.should_not_receive(:m)
>     eval("nil&.unknown(obj.m) { obj.m }")
>   end
> end
> ```

It is documented in the [*Calling Methods* section](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+Navigation+Operator) of the [*Ruby Syntax* documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax_rdoc.html):

> `&.`, called “safe navigation operator”, allows to skip method call when receiver is `nil`. It returns `nil` and doesn't evaluate method's arguments if the call is skipped.