# Rails Pundit Policy Spec test failing with NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, authorization, pundit

I have just started using Pundit for authorization in my current project along with the pundit-matchers gem.

So far it seems to generally be working for me but I have a problem in my tests.

I have generally tried to follow the examples in the [pundit-matchers readme](https://github.com/chrisalley/pundit-matchers) and the Thunderbolt labs blog (http://thunderboltlabs.com/blog/2013/03/27/testing-pundit-policies-with-rspec/).

This is my policy file;

```
#app/policies/procedure_policy.rb
class   ProcedurePolicy
    attr_reader :user, :procedure

    def initialize(user, procedure)
        @user = user
        @procedure = procedure
    end

    def index?
        user.admin?
    end

end
```

And this is my policy_spec file

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ProcedurePolicy do
    subject {described_class.new(user, procedure)}

    let(:procedure) {FactoryGirl.create(:procedure)}

    context "for a guest" do
        let(:user) {nil}
        it {is_expected.not_to permit_action(:index)}
    end

    context "for a non-admin user" do
        let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
        it {is_expected.not_to permit_action(:index)}
    end

    context "for an admin user" do
        let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user)}
        it {is_expected.to permit_action(:index)}
    end

end
```

2 of my 3 tests pass; The `"for a non-admin user"` and `"for an admin user"` ones. The `"for a guest"` test fails with

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass
```

Now I understand why. I'm passing `nil` to the `#index?` method of my ProcedurePolicy class which will not have an `#admin?` method. But all of the example specs I have found online do exactly this. What am I not seeing.

Apologies if I'm missing something really obvious. I've been away from coding for a couple of years.

Comment: Go for [Safe Navigation Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812647/what-does-ampersand-dot-mean-in-ruby) def index? user&.admin? end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "being a visitor" context is for testing authorisation attempts when there is no user currently authenticated in the system. Since no user is logged in, no user record/object exists - the *absence* of a user object is `nil`. This is why both the Thunderbolt Labs and [pundit-matchers](https://rubygems.org/gems/pundit-matchers) examples use nil to represent a visitor. The `nil` object does not have an `admin?` method, causing the error.

To correctly handle nil/guest users in your policy, check that the user object is present before checking if the user is an admin, either by checking the user object directly or using the `present?` method in Rails, e.g.

```
def index?
  user.present? && user.admin?
end
```

or just:

```
def index?
  user && user.admin?
end
```

You'll find that authentication systems such as Devise return `nil` from the `current_user` method when no user is signed in.

Answer (score 2):

Pundit calls the `current_user` method to set `user`, and typically that is provided by an authentication system like Devise or a custom solution. This means that in most scenarios, the expectation is that you always have a layer of authentication before you hit the Pundit logic, so you never have a `user` set to nil when it gets there.

If you want Pundit authorizations to work directly without authentication, you have to handle that in your policy definitions, ex:

```
class ProcedurePolicy    
  def index?
    user.present? && user.admin?
  end
end
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/pundit#Policies

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a custom authentication layer in place that provides the current_user as you have described so technically I don't need to test a nil user. But the examples given at the thunderbolt labs post given above, and at the pundit_matcher github page do have a nil user in their example test so I am just trying to understand how they make them work.