# Is there an "&& Equals" operator in Ruby

Tags: ruby, operators

I often find myself doing things like this:

```
do_something if x && x == y
```

In other works, do something if `x` is not nil, and it has a value of `y`.

It would be nice if I could do something like this instead:

```
do_something if x &&== y
```

Is there an operator that does this?

---

Responses to comments:

---

`x == y` - The problem with this, is that it only tests existence (not nil) if the value of `y` is known. If `y` is itself `nil` then the check fails. So you could end up doing:

```
y && x == y
```

---

`x ||= y` - This would assign the value of `y` to `x` if `x` is nil. That's not what I'm looking for. `x &&= y` doesn't work either for the same reason - it changes the value of `x` to `y` if `x` exists.

---

An example: in my current scenario I want to check that a user has passed to a controller the token associated with them, but I also want to ensure that the token has been assigned. Something like:

```
do_something if user.token && user.token == params[:token]
```

Comment: if x has a value, that means it (x) exists, so it is unnecessary, i think.
because of unnecessity, there is no such operator.

Comment: Assuming `y` has a value, you could just write `... if x == y`

Comment: `x ||= y` should work, no?

Comment: @MuntasirAlam that is an _assignment_ operator the OP is looking for a _comparison_ operator, i.e. `==`, not `=`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @Stefan the assumption that `y` has a value is the problem with `if x == y`

Comment: That's an odd case, isn't it? It translates to _"do something if `x` is not `nil`, and it has a value of `nil`"_ Are you actually facing this problem?

Comment: @Stefan in my current scenario I want to check that a user has passed to a controller the token associated with them, but I also want to ensure that the token has been assigned. Something like `if user.token && user.token == params[:token]`

Comment: That example helps to understand your problem. You should add it to your question.

Comment: @Stefan Good point - I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `ruby` > `2.3.0` you can use the `&.` operator: `x&.== y`. It basically does what `.try` does in `Rails` if the value of the operand is different than `nil` it calls the method and returns its result. If the value is `nil` it returns `nil` so you can do things like: `do_i_exist&.does_the_result_exist&.nil?`

See: [What does &. (ampersand dot) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812647/what-does-ampersand-dot-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: Thanks @hakcho. That looks like what I'm looking for. `x &.== y`. Do you know where the `&.` operator is documented. I can't find it in ruby-docs

Comment: @ReggieB [Calling Methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Receiver) contains a brief note: _"You may use `&.` to designate a receiver, then `my_method` is not invoked and the result is `nil` when the receiver is `nil`. In that case, the arguments of `my_method` are not evaluated."_