# no implicit conversion of StringIO into String (TypeError) - ruby

Tags: json, ruby, jekyll

I have a script called `import.rb` which will import json content from url to drafts directory in jekyll. Below is my code.

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'

# Load JSON data from source
# (Assuming the data source is a json file on your file system)
data = JSON.parse(open('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHFt1Yz96q91-D6eP4uWtRCcF_lzG2WM-sjrpZIr3s02HrICBQ/exec'))

# Proceed to create post files if the value array is not empty
array = data["user"]
if array && !array.empty?
  # create the `_drafts` directory if it doesn't exist already
  drafts_dir = File.expand_path('./_drafts', __dir__)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(drafts_dir) unless Dir.exist?(drafts_dir)

  # iterate through the array and generate draft-files for each entry
  # where entry.first will be the "content" and entry.last the "title"
  array.each do |entry|
    File.open(File.join(drafts_dir, entry.last), 'wb') do |draft|
      draft.puts("---\n---\n\n#{entry.first}")
    end
  end
end
```

When I run `ruby _scripts/import.rb` I get error like

```
3: from _scripts/import.rb:7:in `<main>'
    2: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
    1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/json/common.rb:156:in `new'
    /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/json/common.rb:156:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of StringIO into String (TypeError)
```

Please suggest the corrections.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change this:

```
data = JSON.parse(open('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHFt1Yz96q91-D6eP4uWtRCcF_lzG2WM-sjrpZIr3s02HrICBQ/exec'))
```

To this:

```
data = JSON.parse(open('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHFt1Yz96q91-D6eP4uWtRCcF_lzG2WM-sjrpZIr3s02HrICBQ/exec').string)
```

The `.string` method [`Returns underlying String object`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html#method-i-string).

And while you're at it, change this:

```
array && !array.empty?
```

To this:

```
array&.any?
```

`&.` is the [safe navigation operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36812647/3784008) and it simplifies the process of checking for `nil` and calling a method on the object. And from a style perspective, it's preferred to call `array.any?` over `!array.empty?`.

Finally, when using `FileUtils.mkdir_p` you do not have to include the guard condition `unless Dir.exist?(drafts_dir)`. It can be safely called without concern that it will remove or overwrite the existing directory.

Comment: Thanks, Now I get error like ```2: from _scripts/import.rb:18:in `<main>'
 1: from _scripts/import.rb:18:in `each'
_scripts/import.rb:19:in `block in <main>': undefined method `last' for #<Hash:0x00005600277297a0> (NoMethodError)```

Comment: I assume that you're trying to read the value of the `name` key in the hash (the URL like `https://www.flipkart.com/...`). In that case, change `entry.last` to `entry['name']`, or `entry.fetch('name')`.

Comment: Thanks, now error comes like ```No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/_scripts/_drafts/https://www.flipkart.com/redmi-note-6-pro-black-64-gb/p/itmfayzxqnzjhtbh?affid=xxx,[Flipkart] Redmi Note 6 Pro (Black, 64 GB)  (4 GB RAM) (Errno::ENOENT)```

Comment: fixed it by removing link in the `entry['name']`