# Populating modals with dynamic ids in Rails - undefined local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

So..I’m trying to understand usage of modals in Rails and looking for a few pointers.

I have a list of items at at `category/1` which are being displayed in a loop.  I have a modal which I’m rendering at the bottom of the page with `<%= render "category/update_item_modal" %>`

There’s already a form setup for updating params of each item, but I’m trying to get a modal pop up to specifically just update the title. The modal popup works, and so far I have the following for the button which opens the modal:-

`<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateItemModal-<%= title.id %>"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit Title</button></a>`

And the modal itself:-

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updateItemModal-<%= item.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="updateItemModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="updateItemModalLabel">Change Item</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- UPDATE TITLE HERE? -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives me the error of `undefined local variable "id"` from the modal id for obvious reasons, and this is where my understanding hits a wall.  How do I pass the data from a loop iteration into my modal?

End goal is to have an editable textarea field with the existing title in it, and a submit button which will post the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have defined `@item` in your controller:

```
<%= render "category/update_item_modal", locals: item: @item %>
```

Then you have access to `item` in your partial. One more thing you can do to avoid that error is to use the safe operation operator `item&.id`. More on the safe navigation operator here: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11537

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  What's the term for what you did with `item&.id`?  I've seen this before but want to read up on it further.

Comment: That's the safe navigation operator. I added a link, but there are a few helpful answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812647/what-does-ampersand-dot-mean-in-ruby

Comment: Great, thanks.  I had to wrap the above like so `{item: item}` for it to work.  Next issue is that I don't have @item in my controller as there's about 100 of them on the `show` page I'm working on... I only have access to @category which holds all the items.