# How do I prevent my Rails controller method from returning nil to my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty, openweathermap

I have a simple app that calls an API and returns weather data. A user is able to search for a city and the current temperature is returned. I have a problem though, when the search field is empty or a city that isn't recognised I get an error `undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass`. Here is my code:

forecasts_controller.rb

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController
  def current_weather
    @token = Rails.application.credentials.openweather_key
    @city = params[:q]
    if @city == nil
      @forecast = ""
    else
      @forecast = OpenWeatherApi.new(@city, @token).my_location_forecast
    end
  end
end
```

services/open_weather_api.rb

```
class OpenWeatherApi
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "http://api.openweathermap.org"

  def initialize(city, appid)
    @options = { query: { q: city, APPID: appid } }
  end

  def my_location_forecast
    self.class.get("/data/2.5/weather", @options)
  end
end
```

current_weather.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(current_weather_forecasts_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %><br>

<p>Current temperature: <%= @forecast['main']['temp'].to_i - 273 %>°C</p>
```

Obviously the code `['main']['temp'].to_i - 273` can't be called on `nil`, but how do I prevent `@forecast` from being `nil` when nothing is passed in the form or when the API doesn't recognise the city?

Comment: Why not wrap that line in `<% if @forecast.present? %> ... <% end %>`? Also, defaulting `@forecast` to `""` is not idiomatic, it's better to just define it as `nil` (or just don't define it at all, because instance variables are nil by default anyway).

Answer (score 1):

You might try...

```
if @city.nil?
  @forecast = {}
```

To ensure `@forecast` always responds as a hash, And then in your view you can use `dig` which will let you drill down into a hash even for nodes that are not present...

```
<p>Current temperature: <%= @forecast.dig('main', 'temp').to_i - 273 %>°C</p>
```

But better might be

```
<% if @forecast.present? %>
  <p>Current temperature: <%= @forecast.dig('main', 'temp').to_i - 273 %>°C</p>
<% else %>
  <p>You need to select a city!</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Problem with this is that it shows `You need to select a city!` when the page is loaded at first.

Comment: It also returns `Current temperature: -273°C` if a city is entered that the API doesn't recognise.

Comment: Look at what the API returns for the condition of unrecognized or blank city. It should be enough info for you to wrap an error paragraph in an if block.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Safe Navigation Operator (`&`) before each method to prevent this.

```
<p>Current temperature: <%= @forecast['main']['temp']&.to_i - 273 %>°C</p>
```

Refer to [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812647/what-does-ampersand-dot-mean-in-ruby) to learn more about it.

Basically, it prevents `undefined method for nil:NilClass` from happening. if a value is empty/nil.

Comment: Except the undefined method is referring to the square brackets, not the `to_i`

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Ah yes, you're right. I'm not sure how to apply it to `@forcast` then. Would it be directly before or after the object? Is it even possible in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can `try` for brackets in rails... `[:a, :b, :c].try(:[], 1)` or in this case `@forecast.try(:[], 'main')` and chained would be `@forecast.try(:[], 'main').try(:[], 'temp')` but an interesting weirdness is that `nil.to_i` returns `0` but `nil.try(:to_i)` returns `nil`.

Comment: I had been searching a couple days for proper use of this.  I just needed the ampersand, not the '.to_i' part.  
'
Like

`<p>Current city: <%= @forecast['main']['city']& %>°</p>`

Comment: @Chnikki `.to_i` is "to integer" which is specific to the OP's question. Use `&` before a method to allow it to pass when pulling from a parameter that is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Taking advantage of the last comment you can wrap this logic in a view object and do something like this as an option:

```
class ForecastsController < ApplicationController
  def current_weather
    @city = params[:q]

    @temperature = ForecastView.new(city).temperature
  end
end

class ForecastView
  DESCRIPTIVE_NAME_HERE = 273

  def initialize(city)
    @city = city
    @token = Rails.application.credentials.openweather_key
  end

  def temperature
    forecast.dig('main', 'temp').to_i - DESCRIPTIVE_NAME_HERE
  end

  private

  attr_reader :city, :token

  def forecast
    return {} if city.blank?

    OpenWeatherApi.new(city, token).my_location_forecast
  end
end

<p>Current temperature: <%= @temperature %>°C</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
<p>Current temperature: <%= @forecast['main']['temp'].to_i - 273 if @forcast['main']['temp'].present? %>°C</p>
```