# Better way to check 2 conditions based on 1 object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I commonly need to use this kind of methods where I have to check if an object exists and if this object returns a specific value or a behavior. Is that a better way to write this code?

```
def set_current_theme
   if current_tenant && current_tenant.has_custom_domain?
     @theme = Theme.last || Theme.create
   end
end
```

At a first glance, I would just add one conditional: `if current_tenant.has_custom_domain?` and that should be enough. But the result is generally that there is no such method (in this case `has_custom_domain?`) for nil class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest early return (so called [guard clause](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#no-nested-conditionals)) instead of :if statement, because you don't have :else clause:

```
def set_current_theme
  return unless current_tenant&.has_custom_domain?

  @theme = Theme.last || Theme.create
end
```

Comment: even better. i forgot about guard clause.

Comment: great! I didn't know that one!

Answer (score 2):

Shorter (and i think better) way is to use `&.` (it's shorthand for `try!`) like this.

```
if current_tenant&.has_custom_domain?
  @theme = Theme.last || Theme.create
end
```

[What does &. (ampersand dot) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36812647/what-does-ampersand-dot-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very useful. I had never really understood the use of the ampersand.