# How to cause rerender of 2 components linked with database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Suppose I have 2 components which are not linked (by props) A and B. They are linked but by the database, A has a button which allows it to change the database. And I want B to rerender (not all the page) when the database changes, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&.` is called a safe navigation operator which was introduced in ruby 2.3, it works similar to the `try!` method and returns nil if the object is nil else returns the attribute value of the object.

```
object = OpenStruct.new(a: 1)
object&.a
# => 1 

object = nil
object&.a
# => nil 

object.a
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#         1: from (irb):21
# NoMethodError (undefined method `a' for nil:NilClass)
```

You can see in the above example the difference when we are calling `a` on an object with and without `&.` operator.

Refer [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36812667/5783088) for more details on it.